# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.rpc'; 'solana' is not a package

Tags: python, token, blockchain, solana

I install solana API via https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/, lib install successful and I can access to lib. So when run them with python3 i receive message error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solana.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solana.rpc.api import Client
  File "/home/trannguyenhan/CodeFolder/blockchain_wallet_automation/solana.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solana.rpc.api import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.rpc'; 'solana' is not a package
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this means that the package was installed somewhere else, or wasn't installed at all.  If you're using python3, you can check all of this work in a venv by running:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ ./venv/bin/pip install solana
$ ./venv/bin/python3
>>> from solana.rpc.api import Client
```

And then all of your great code after that!

Also, the name of the file is `solana.py`, which conflicts with the `solana` from the library that you've installed.  Python will resolve to your local file first, and it fails to find the type from library.  You should rename the file from `solana.py` to anything else.

More information about how to install with pip at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/, and more information about using venv at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I still meet above error after follow your steps

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed the issue, your file is called `solana.py` which conflicts with the name of the library.  Be sure to change it to something else!